# Trouble Connecting to AWS MySQL using DataGrip

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, datagrip

I have set up an RDS, MySQL database on AWS and now want to start running SQL on it using the datagrips IDE. After installing AWS Command Line Tools and the AWS plugin for DataGrip, I tried to connect to my MySQL database on AWS, but I keep getting a communications failure--the database won't respond to my request.

Screenshot of the error code when testing connection:

[image]

DataGrip AWS plugin seems to be working--I can navigate to my created database.

[image]

I can give more details upon request, though I am hesitant in sharing too much more here for security reasons. And even if you can't exactly solve my problem, I would be interested in places to start or things to try.

I guess I already have one theory... the AWS doc mentioned that I need Docker installed. I do have Docker installed, but I wouldn't be surprised if it's not configured properly or something, as I've never used it. Not sure if that is related, but just putting it out there...

EDIT: including SG details

[image]

[image]

Let me know if I need to include or dis-include information.

Comment: What is the SG on the RDS DB?

Comment: this cretainly looks like a network problem(need to check your sgs and routes). Are you able to telnet to the mysql server on port configured. There really isnt anything extra that you need to do on datagrip to be honest.

Comment: What do you mean by SG? @ErmiyaEskandary

Comment: I haven't tried telnet but I did ping the link in my terminal (what datagrips recommended) and it kept saying "request for timeout for icmp seq" over and over again. That sounds bad... ?

Comment: SG means security groups.  So yup , its definitly a network issue that you have. It maybe your VPC configurations or even the security group that you have defined for the rds.

Comment: @John Sorensen Security group - can you please paste the details of the security group you have for the database and VPC details if it is in one?

Comment: Ok, I'm viewing my security group details now--not sure what is relevant so I'll edit my question to include a screenshot of (what I think are) the security group details. Let me know if I need to edit me screenshot to hide potentially sensitive information. I'm new to AWS and I may not be aware of stuff

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to connect to an RDS Aurora DB, make sure to choose the appropriate driver for it.

[image]

Comment: Same issue, this solved it